# Using ruby and graphviz on heroku with heroku-buildpack-multi

Tags: ruby, heroku, graphviz

I'm trying to deploy my app on heroku. I use declarative_authorization with graphical visualisation.

I installed `https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi` `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi` and created `.buildpacks` with:

```
https://github.com/stigkj/heroku-buildpack-graphviz.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

Building works fine:

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/stigkj/heroku-buildpack-graphviz.git
=====> Detected Framework: graphviz
-----> Fetching and installing graphviz
       grapvhiz installed
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
```

But now I get when I access the graph:

```
Errno::ENOENT in AuthorizationRulesController#graph
No such file or directory - dot -q -Tsvg
```

What is the correct path?

Comment: Have you tried logging in to the remote machine with `heroku run bash` and tried finding out for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/weibeld/heroku-buildpack-graphviz is a stable buildpack for Graphviz (see instructions there).

It automatically adds the location of `dot` and other Graphviz executables to the `PATH`.

Comment: Short and clear, it works! ty

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/gokceneraslan/heroku-buildpack-graphviz instead of https://github.com/stigkj/heroku-buildpack-graphviz.git.

Then, add this configuration:

```
heroku config:add PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/bin
```

Source: https://github.com/pygram/pygram#deployment-on-heroku